# How to identify iPad model based solely on Serial Number?

Tags: ipad

I have the serial number of a remote iPad Pro and would like to know if it is a Gen 2 or 3.  The device is not accessible so I can not read the model number off the back.

Answer (score 4):

[This Apple page](https://checkcoverage.apple.com) checks support, warranty, and AppleCare availability for Apple products.

Entering an Apple device serial number, however, will also display that device's model and type. I just tried it with the iMac on which I'm typing this answer, and it returned the correct information. Should work as well on your mystery iPad.

EDIT: `[This more specific Apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201471) identifies the iPad model from its serial number. I don't have an iPad so I can't check if it provides the detail you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The Apple website did not return the model number, but it did return "iPad Pro Wi-Fi + Cellular"

Comment: @gatorback Oh well. It was worth a try.

Comment: The more specific page looks up iPod, not iPad.

Comment: @SlogmeisterExtraordinaire Thanks. I corrected the reference.

Answer (score 1):

I always use [EveryMac.com](https://everymac.com) to lookup specs of all Apple devices.

You can go to their [iPad lookup page](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=DMPVD91EJ28K) to search by serial number.  It will tell you a good level of details of the device.

For example, this is what was returned when I did a lookup by my iPad’s serial number:

[image: iPad description.]

Hopefully, this will give you the info you’re looking for.

Comment: Is it a good idea to send serial numbers to websites? I could once set up an apple support appointment solely using serial number of my friend's iPhone. I dont know the worst that can be done..

Comment: @ankii Serial numbers are not really private info. You see all the time on eBay and other similar sites. Nobody can do anything with just a serial number. I'm not worried about it, based on what I know, but to each his own.